# TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable Python 3.4.2

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am wanting to write a code in Python 3.4.2 that takes a string of numbers, separates them and then puts them in reverse order. So far I have:

```
#input string
numberIntegers = 123456
#assign each character to an idex
zeroDigit = numberIntegers[0]
oneDigit = numberIntegers[1]
secondDigit = numberIntegers[2]
thirdDigit = numberIntegers[3]
fourthDigit = numberIntegers[4]
fifthDigit = numberIntegers[5]
print(" The numbers to reverse:  {}".format(numberIntegers))
print(" The digits, in order, are: {} {} {} {} {} {}".format(zeroDigit,oneDigit,secondDigit,thirdDigit,fourthDigit,fifthDigit))
print(" The numbers in reverse: ")
```

Comment: Your *"input string"* **isn't a string!** Try `numberIntegers = str(123456)` or `numberIntegers = '123456'`. Also, note that `print(" The digits, in order, are: {} {} {} {} {} {}".format(*numberIntegers)` would save you the separate names.

Comment: If I was to leave it as a integer, would there still be a way to separate them, or do I have to convert them into a string?

Comment: You could do it mathematically, but it's much easier with a string. Integers don't really *have* digits, that's just the way they're displayed *in decimal form* (e.g. `0x1e240 == 123456 == 0b11110001001000000 == 0361100`, so which "digits" should you get?)

Answer (score 0):

`numberIntegers` is an integer rather than a string. Change like so:

```
numberIntegers = '123456'
```